# Using Team Viewer while port 5938 is blocked?

Tags: remote-desktop, teamviewer

Title says it all, is it possible to use Team Viewer in an environment where port 5938 is being blocked?  Is there some kind of setting that can be used to establish connections over a different port, or is this a hard requirement?

Comment: Why is 5938 blocked? Is this a business environment? If so, is TeamViewer a requirement in your job? If so, you should ask your IT department. If it is not a requirement, why are you trying to use it?

Comment: I thought TeamViewer used HTTP (80) or HTTPS (443) ports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If TeamViewer can’t connect over TCP port 5938, it will next try to connect over
TCP port 443, and finally it will try on TCP port 80.

However, if running on Android or Windows Mobile, it can can only connect over port 5938.

If all these ports are blocked, then you are in trouble.

Source: [Which ports are used by TeamViewer?](https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/Knowledge-Base/Which-ports-are-used-by-TeamViewer/ta-p/4139)